# How to get the following transfer function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

I was wondering if there is a Matlab code that can calculate the following TF from the 2 equations below. Thank You

[image: Transfer Function]

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Yes Matlab can do transfer functions, there are many approaches that you can take.

Comment: Do you have access to the Control Systems Toolbox?  It'll make computing this very easy.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I do can access, Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Symbolic Math Toolbox can be used here:

```
syms alpha theta delta s
    % we have to solve the system
sol= solve([(88.5*s+3.13)*alpha+(-88.5*s+2.06)*theta==-4.63*delta,...
    -11.27*alpha+(4.75*s^2+0.321*s)*theta==-34.25*delta] ,[theta delta])
tfuncsym= sol.theta/sol.delta % the transfer function (sym object)
[n,d]= numden(tfuncsym);
    % the transfer function (tf object)
tf_object= tf(fliplr(double(coeffs(n))),fliplr(double(coeffs(d))))
    % the transfer function (zpk object)
    % this is exactly what we need
zpk_object= zpk(tf_object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: You should mention you're using the control systems toolbox as well.